# How to get weights from the bestModel of CrossValidator MultilayerPerceptronClasiffier - Spark mllib - Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have managed to obtain the best model and the best parameters of a model in which I have used **CrossValidator** in **MultilayerPerceptronClassifier**, but I cannot achieve the **weights**, I have tried in some ways but I cannot. I am using Zeppelin and Spark 2.3.2.

```
layers=[4,4,4]

mlpc = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(layers=layers, seed=12345L, blockSize=624)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="accuracy")

pipelineMLPC = Pipeline(stages=[mlpc])

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(mlpc.maxIter, range(135,136)) \
    .addGrid(mlpc.tol, [1E-3,1E-4]) \
    .addGrid(mlpc.solver, ["l-bfgs"]) \
    .build()

cvPipeline = CrossValidator(estimator = pipelineMLPC,
                    estimatorParamMaps = paramGrid,
                    evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="accuracy"),
                    numFolds = 2)

cvModelPipeline = cvPipeline.fit(train);


#Make predictions on test
prediction = cvModelPipeline.transform(test)

#Obtiene el Accuracy del mejor modelo
predictionAndLabels = prediction.select("prediction", "label")
accuracy_test = evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels)
print("Accuracy test = " + str(accuracy_test))

#Obtiene el mejor modelo 
bestModelMLPC = cvModelPipeline.bestModel.stages[-1]._java_obj.parent()

#Obtiene los mejores parámetros del mejor modelo
bestMaxIter = bestModelMLPC.getMaxIter()
bestTol = bestModelMLPC.getTol()
bestSolver = bestModelMLPC.getSolver()
bestBlockSize = bestModelMLPC.getBlockSize()
bestSeed = bestModelMLPC.getSeed()


bestWeights = bestModelMLPC.weights
print(bestWeights)
#bestModelMLPC.weights 
#bestModelMLPC.weight
#bestModelMLPC.getClassifier().weights
#bestModelMLPC.getClassifier().weight

print("Best Params: maxIter = " + str(bestMaxIter) + "; tol = " + str(bestTol) + "; solver = " + str(bestSolver) + "; blockSize = " + str(bestBlockSize) + ";  seed = " + str(bestSeed) + "; initialWeights = " + str(bestWeights))
```

**With this I get some java but I don't get the weight values that is what I need. Anyone have any idea how I can get it.**

```
Accuracy test = 0.392935019625
<py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7efe75d45190>
Best Params: maxIter = 135; tol = 0.001; solver = l-bfgs; blockSize = 624;  seed = 12345; initialWeights = <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7efe75d45190>
```